# Include and configure MDC theme colors

Tags: css, material-design

Hi Im new to MDC and we have an MVC web app that we are trying to use mdc, I added MDC client side library to the project.

How do we properly configure mdc theme colors  and then use those settings for colors in our css?

I'm seeing this on web tools Elements even if I tried step 3 on
https://material.io/develop/web/theming/theming-guide and changed the colors, the colors is always purple.

[mdc theme colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGivB.png)

I would like to configure --mdc-theme* colors so we can also use it like;

on themesettings.scss?

```
--mdc-theme-primary : #008080
```

on css:

```css
.myframe { 
   background: var(--mdc-theme-primary);
}
```

maybe there is something missing in my implementation, I tried different things online but I cant make it to change the theme colors, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the themes will only apply to imported web components.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32930825)